# is_page not work in after_setup_theme action

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hook, action

I need detect page type(page/post) and move js to footer.

I make this code [image]

But is_page function always return false in this action (after_setup_theme). How am i can correctly check current page type (post/page)?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong hook

WordPress can not find out whether you're on a page or a homepage when the `after_setup_theme` is fired.

You should use [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook

Comment: How do we find out the page using the 'after_theme_setup' hook?